# VSTO Document-level customization security and trust

Tags: .net, ms-word, vsto, clickonce

We are creating a suit of Word 2010 templates using document level cusomisations. These will be stored on a network drive where everybody will have access to.
We have signed the click once deployment and added the certificate to the trusted publishers and the shared drive is in the trusted locations. This works fine when creating a new document, but when the document is saved to another location and reopened the user is informed that its not trusted and it doesnt load.

Is it possible to allow a document to load from an location providing the customisation it is loading is trusted?

(as a side note, documents will be created and saved to a few hundred network drives and locations and it isnt really feasable to add them all to the trusted locations)

Comment: You should be able to change the Office security settings. The question is are you allowed to do so?

Comment: We can modify the trust centre settings via group policy across the company, but I dont really want to have to specify every network location mainly from a maintenance point of view.